Locomotive-scroll, scrollbar not functioning right
Using locomotive-scroll overrides the default scrollbar. But the one its replaced with seems broken.
It looks like its being scrolled itself. In the code pen, I have left everything default apart from scrollbar width to make it easier to see. I know I am missing something. Can anyone help me understand why its broken. thanks
code pen : https://codepen.io/P-Mattie/pen/rNgaYRq
I tried stripping it down to out of the box locomotive. And Its broken. I feel like its a data attribute or something I didn't include.
<html lang="en">
  <body data-scroll-container>
    <div class="red box"></div>
    <div class="blue box"></div>
    <div class="red box"></div>
    <div class="blue box"></div>
  </body>
</html>

import LocomotiveScroll from "https://esm.sh/locomotive-scroll";
const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
  el: document.querySelector("[data-scroll-container]"),
  smooth: true,
  scrollFromAnywhere: true,
});

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0%;
}

.box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

.red {
  background-color: rgb(255, 175, 175);
}

.blue {
  background-color: rgb(147, 147, 255);
}

/* locomotive base css */

/*! locomotive-scroll v4.1.3 | MIT License | https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll */
html.has-scroll-smooth {
  overflow: hidden;
}

html.has-scroll-dragging {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.has-scroll-smooth body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.has-scroll-smooth [data-scroll-container] {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] [data-scroll-container] {
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] [data-scroll-section] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.c-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 11px;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center right;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.c-scrollbar:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.45);
}
.c-scrollbar:hover,
.has-scroll-scrolling .c-scrollbar,
.has-scroll-dragging .c-scrollbar {
  opacity: 1;
}
[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar:hover {
  transform: scaleY(1.3);
}

.c-scrollbar_thumb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}
.has-scroll-dragging .c-scrollbar_thumb {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar_thumb {
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

